# Excel Text to column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Does any of you know if exist any function to split the double brake line to column? I do know how to split by spaces like: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2;CHAR(13);"");CHAR(10);"|")`, but I want something like the image bellow:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The solution is depend on your string. If you have only one separation as shown, you can use following equations.

for the 1st part

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),",",1),FIND(",",SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),",",1),1)-1)
```

for the 2nd part

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),",",1),FIND(",",SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),",",1),1)+1,10000)
```

This is independent from the number of consecutive char(10) characters between text.

Answer (score 1):

Just use two different formulas, there are many ways you could go about it.  Say something like `=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(10),A1))` for the first column and `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(CHAR(10),A1))` for the second one.